# How to run JDBC code from Mac terminal?

Tags: java, jdbc, terminal

> I realize this is a duplicate question, but there was never an answer
>   chosen for the one that I've seen and I've tried what they recommended
>   and it didn't work. I am brand new to compiling and running `Java` from
>   terminal. I always use eclipse. When using eclipse, I have no problem
>   connecting to my database and running my code. I've made a `classpath`by 
>   clicking on my `Java` project and then going to `Properties` then `Build Path` and 
>   added my `MySQl` `jar`. However, when trying to run my code from the
>   terminal I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at Database.createConnection(Database.java:31)
        at Database.verifiedMember(Database.java:876)
        at Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

> I've compiled my program by doing:
>   `javac *.java -cp /Users/Administrator/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar`
>
> Running it by: 
>   `java Main -cp /Users/Administrator/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar`
>
> I've also tried just doing
>   `javac *.java` and `java Main`
>   But I get the same results.
>
> What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to execute a program through terminal is

java [-options] class [args...]

So, you need to provide your classpatth before your class name. With the way you are trying, -cp and jarpath will be considered as program arguments.

It should look like below

```
java -cp /Users/Administrator/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:.: Main
```

That should work

Comment: Now I am getting `Could not find or load main class Main`. I recompiled by doing `javac -cp /Users/Administrator/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar *.java` just in case that was the problem but it still gives me the same error. I know `Main` should at least run because I ran it earlier, but when it had to connect to the database is when I would get the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` error

Comment: `java Main -cp /Users/Administrator/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` was getting my program to run, but it just wouldn't connect my program to my database. So I would get an error when I made a call to the database.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. You need to mention your current directory also into classpath

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly!